# “Queen” vs. “Königin”

Tags: word-usage

Is it just an example of an English word creeping in to use in German, or is there a particular reason why *Queen* is used rather than *Königin*?

And does *Die Queen* always refer to Elizabeth II of the United Kingdom, or is it used for other female monarchs as well?

Comment: If talk about "The Queen" in Germany everyone thinks of "Her Majesty The Queen of Britain". Queen is used as an alias.

Comment: use http://www.google.com/trends to find out what current terms are more common in specific local regions. imho the most up to date database available to see what terms people as keyword/common term and which term is used in internet news

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Duden there are three meanings for German *["die Queen"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Queen)*:

> 1. britische Königin
> 2. *(umgangssprachlich)* weibliche Person, die in einer Gruppe, in ihrer Umgebung aufgrund bestimmter Vorzüge im Mittelpunkt steht
> 3. *(Jargon)* sich feminin gebender Homosexueller

By far the most used meaning is however [Her Majesty The Queen of Britain](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elisabeth_II.). This can best be seen e.g. by performing an image search on [German Google](http://www.google.de) for *"die Queen"*.

By looking up [Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=K%C3%B6nigin%20von%20England,die%20Queen&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) we can see that today *"die Queen"* is used almost as often as *"Königin von England"*:

[image]

Comment: The Duden... What's sated there as "proper German" by this time is a joke. For example: plural of Pizza and Taxi -> Pizzas and Taxis is correct (so called "Neue deutsche Rechtschreibung") -_- it's horrible... should still only be: Pizzen and Taxen :-) Back to topic: no one would ever use 2. and 3. in Germany ;-)

Comment: **i strongly doubt the statistical significance of ngrams here ;)** What average joe reads book about this topic or writes one :) Google Trends shows used search keywords and frequency of terms in (boulevard) news. Much more reliable to see what terms in local mass media are more common imo. Probably biography/history books use all *Königin* but i never heard *königin von england* in mass media...

Answer (score 5):

I can think of some reasons why we use `Die Queen` in German, but refer to `Königin Beatrix der Niederlande`.
Most people in Germany understand a fair amount of English, at least in ex-west-Germany. We say `President Obama` as well, for example.

We had a time of occupation were the English language could greatly influence our own, and there is the British national anthem `God save the Queen` that is, at least for its title, known to some degree in Germany.

So yeah, if you talk about `Die Queen` in Germany, you are talking about Elizabeth.

Comment: Do you say _President_ or _Präsident_? Not much difference to my ear...

Comment: @Brian "President" and "Präsident" are pronounced quite differently. The German word is stressed on the last syllable and the letter R is pronounced in the throat.

Comment: In Germany we say "Präsident (der vereinigten Staaten von Amerika) Obama" or easy Barack Obama, der Präsident der vereinigten Staaten.

Comment: just edited the shaving out of the answer, I think Takkat is right and trying to be funny won't help in finding an answer.

Answer (score 4):

[image]
 <sup>Blue: "Queen", Red: "Königin", Green & Orange: "Prince William"</sup>

[Look up Google Trend](http://www.google.com/trends?q=%22Queen%22+%2C+%22K%C3%B6nigin%22+%2C+%22prinz+william%22+%2C+%22prince+william%22&ctab=0&geo=de&geor=all&date=all&sort=0) to see how germans use it. The more often search of *queen* in Germany instead of *Königin* makes it pretty clear imo.

Its the same like *King of Pop* (Michael Jackson), *King of Rock'n'Roll* (Elvis Presley). You hear *König des Pop* nearly never in german TV and Radio. A mixture of convention, Denglish and Boulevard media influence. But in the mass media they all refer to the same english term.

PS: Also the british royals are like a *eine schreckliche nette Familie (Married...with children)* in the german boulevard media, they get the most attention of the european royals. So *Queen* is synonym to *Queen Elizabeth of Britain*.

Comment: What an epic analysis XDDDD

Comment: @infinit despite al bundy would never betray peggy :D